# Name new dataframes from character vectors - loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I think this one is easy but I still can't figure it out and I really need help with this. I've looked everywhere but still couldn't find it.

Let's say I have this vector:

```
filenames <- c("fn1", "fn2", "fn3")
```

And I want to associate them with an dataframe that is created according to a function, that is generated at that time

```
df|name from filenames[i]| <- df
```

so it would return these dataframes

```
dffn1
dffn2
dffn3
```

I hope I made myself clear. My problem is create a new data frame and name it according to a list or whatever, in a for loop.

Comment: This is not a fun pattern to work with in R. A list of data.frames rather than a bunch of variables would be better. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames

Comment: You can create all the dataframes and store them in a list using a string (`names(ListofDFs)=nameString`), then name the list. It's also easier for R to work with a list of df's instead of a bunch of df's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assign` to achieve what you want.

```
for(nms in filenames){
 assign(paste('df',nms,sep=''), df) }
```